# How to get a file from POST data in python CGI script?

Tags: python, file, curl, post, cgi

I'm trying to upload a file using cURL and retrieve it from the other side via a CGI Python3 script and save it with the same name.

My current cURL request:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @file.xlsx http://10.0.0.1/cgi-bin/test.py
```

How can I handle this file python script side?

Comment: Did my answer below work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you have to read binary data from from "stdin", which would be issuing a read against `sys.stdin.buffer`, which returns bytes:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cgi
import cgitb
import sys

cgitb.enable()

data = sys.stdin.buffer.read()
with open(`file.xlsx`, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
print('Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n', end='')
print('Success!')
```

**Update**

If you want to send (upload) a file *and* other data, then you need to send *multipart/encoded* data, which means you have to use `curl` with `-F` options. For example:

```
curl -X POST -F "file=@file.xlsx" -F "ip=10.0.0.2" 10.0.0.1/cgi-bin/test.py
```

Then your Python script becomes:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cgi
import cgitb
import os

cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
ip = form.getvalue('ip')
fileitem = form['file']
data = fileitem.file.read()
# this is the base name of the file that was uploaded:
filename = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename) # or just use 'file.xlsx' or whatever
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
print('Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n', end='')
print('Success!')
```

Comment: thanks! What if I want to send multiple parameters, for example: curl -X POST --data-binary "file=@file.xlsx"  --data "ip=10.0.0.2" http://10.0.0.1/cgi-bin/test.py